# Unfortunately my app has stopped in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, emulation

I've been looking for an answer for hours now, but my calculator wont work at all :(

I appreciate if you could help me. I've posted the manifest code below. Inform me if you need to see the MainActivity.java or anything else :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
     android:name="com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

The errors shown on Logcat

```
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Process: com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx,     PID: 895
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx/com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity.onClickListeners(MainActivity.java:49)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-16 18:09:59.890: E/AndroidRuntime(895):  ... 11 more
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Process: com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx, PID: 1100
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx/com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity.onClickListeners(MainActivity.java:49)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which is the logcat error report?

Comment: There is a huge list of errors, but i don't know what to do or how to begin. I'm very new at this and this is my first app...

Comment: When your app crashes a bunch of red lines will print to logcat, post all of those.

Comment: I just edited the first post with all the errors.

Comment: Now post the `onCreate()` and `onClickListeners()` methods of your Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your key lines

```
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 18:16:23.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1100):     at com.example.elof_calc_2000_dragonslayerxx.MainActivity.onClickListeners(MainActivity.java:49)
```

You have a NullPointerException on line 49 of your MainActivity. You can post that for further help. Whatever code is there ensure that it is initialized (and thus not null) before you call it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved my problem :) Forgot to add actionListener to a button... typical me...

Comment: Easy mistake, happy you got it solved!